# How to get the x:Name of the Grid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i want to Know the x:Name of the Grid child as in this case :

```
<Grid x:Name="one" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="49.667,15,15,15">
        <Grid x:Name="container1" Background="Red" Margin="10"/>
        </Grid>
    <Button Content="mov" Foreground="White" x:Name="first" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,44.833,0,70.167" Width="29.334" Background="Black" Click="first_Click"/>
```

and here the code when i click :

```
private void first_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var ttt = FindVisualChild<Grid>(one);
        MessageBox.Show(ttt.ToString());

    }

    private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When i click the message just show this content "System.Window.Controls.Grid" instead i want to know the x:name  in this case "container1" then i ask  kindly if you have any suggestion that i can receive the x:Name of the Grid.

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely

Comment: Did you try `ttt.Name`?

Comment: @dkozl Yes,You are right!!!Thank you so much for that...if you reply like an answer i will mark it !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to dkozl for providing you the answer in the comments of the OP. I wanted to give a bit of additional information to supplement it.

Any element that is exposed to you within the XAML can be accessed in the code-behind as a property (there are some exceptions but for the most part this rings true).

```
<Grid x:Name="one" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="49.667,15,15,15">
        <Grid x:Name="container1" Background="Red" Margin="10"/>
        </Grid>
    <Button Content="mov" Foreground="White" x:Name="first" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,44.833,0,70.167" Width="29.334" Background="Black" Click="first_Click"/>
```

If you wanted to, you can access the Grid properties like

```
private void first_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.one.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
    this.one.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 10, 25);
}
```

You also do not need to use the visual tree lookup since you have provided a name to the grid, providing the code-behind is associated with the view that holds the two grids.

You can just do:

```
private void first_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this.container1.Name);
}
```